# Process terminated with status 1 in code blocks

Tags: c, embedded

While I was trying to build files, it came as process terminated with status 1 in build log. I'm currently learning atmega328p and I used that for this project (horn system) and I have whole code here [hornsystem](https://github.com/saravanan849/hornsystem/tree/main). Can anyone help me out and this is the build log.

```
------------- Build: Debug in casestudy (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler for AVR)---------------

avr-gcc.exe -LC:\WinAVR\avr\lib -o bin\Debug\casestudy.elf obj\Debug\fuse.o obj\Debug\GPIO.o obj\Debug\Hornstate.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\modes.o 
obj\Debug\temperature.o  -mmcu=atmega328p -Wl,-Map=bin\Debug\casestudy.map,--cref  
obj\Debug\Hornstate.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `default_dutycycle'
obj\Debug\GPIO.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
obj\Debug\main.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `default_dutycycle'
obj\Debug\GPIO.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
obj\Debug\modes.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `default_dutycycle'
obj\Debug\GPIO.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
obj\Debug\temperature.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `default_dutycycle'
obj\Debug\GPIO.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: The error says "multiple definition of `default_dutycycle`" and tells you the files where it was defined. In file `GPIO.h` you have `unsigned int default_dutycycle = 77;` and this header was included by several other files. It is better not to define variables or functions in headers files: only their declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the information, error solved. I thought, since I have used `ifndef`, `unsigned int default_dutycycle` will not be defined each time in `main.c`.

Comment: `#ifndef` as a 'header guard' is to protect from circular inclusion, not inclusion in multiple compilation units.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you have found a solution to your problem it would be very helpful if you described it in an answer and then accepted that answer - that woul help other users with a similar issue find the solution more quickly. If I could also suggest editing your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do - eg what is it you are trying to build and on what are you trying to build it, that might also help other users in identifying your problem as the same as theirs. Cheers.

Comment: Do not link to off-site code.  Include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: `0 error(s), 0 warning(s)` - your build system is clearly broken!  Perhaps only counting compiler errors and not linker errors?

Answer (score 0):

Read (and fix) build logs from the top *not* from the bottom.  The error you are referring to simply means the build failed.  The reason for failure is described earlier.

The process that has terminated is I guess the project builder (`make` most likely). `make` (or whatever the build system is) terminates when the build is either complete or it fails.

Here the linker step of the build has failed for the reasons given in the preceding lines. The actual error is:

> ```
> obj\Debug\Hornstate.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `default_dutycycle'
> ```

The subsequent lines tell you wher ethe multiple definitions are mde:  main.o, GPIO.o, Hornstate.o, modes.o and temperature.o.

Most likely you have a header file included by all these that contains a *definition* where it should only contain a *declaration*.  For example if you have a file temperature.h with:

```
int default_dutycycle = 50 ;
```

That is a *definition* and will be duplicated in every source that includes temperature.h.  Instead temperature.h should contain:

```
extern int default_dutycycle ;
```

The the temperature.c might then contain:

```
int default_dutycycle = 50 ;
```

An alternative if `default_dutycycle` is a constant is you define it as a *macro* in the header file:

```
#define default_dutycycle 50
```

Though convention would dictate capitalisation:

```
#define DEFAULT_DUTYCYCLE 50
```

Comment: Note I did not follow the off-site link to the actual code in the question  - and do not intend to.  Hence the answer includes guesses about what the code contains.  Comments from those that have looked at it suggest that the symbol is in GPIO.h rather than temperature.h - but the principle stands.